# Python: calling function from imported file

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you call a function from an imported file? for example:

Test:

```
import test2
def aFunction():
    print "hi there"
```

Test2:

```
import test
aFunction()
```

This give me a name error, saying my function isn't defined. I've also tried:

```
from test import aFunction
```

And:

```
from test import *
```

I've also tried not importing test2 in test. I'm coming to Python from C++, so I fear I'm missing something blatantly obvious to veteran Python progammers...

Comment: Your `from test import aFunction` should have worked, what error did you see?

Comment: Note that there is also a [`test` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) included with Python, you could be importing *that* instead.

Comment: I was having the same error in my larger project, I created the test files just to show my problem.
I was getting the error "Import Error: Could not import name 'aFunction'".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are creating a circular import. `test.py` imports `test2.py` which tries to import `test.py`.

Don't do this. By the time `test2` imports `test`, that module has not completed executing all the code; the function is not yet defined:

- `test` is compiled and executed, and an empty module object is added to `sys.modules`.
- The line `import test2` is run.

  - `test2` is compiled and executed, and an empty module object is added to `sys.modules`.
  - The line `import test` is run.

    - `test` is already present as a module in `sys.modules`, this object is returned and bound to the name `test`.
  - A next line tries to run `test.aFunction()`. No such name exists in `test`. An exception is raised.
- The lines defining `def aFunction()` are never executed, because an exception was raised.

Remove the `import test2` line, and run `test2.py` *directly*, and importing the function will work fine:

```
import test

test.aFunction()
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation of how the imports resolved. Someone I chatted with yesterday (with a heavy Java background) was really surprised with the way importing actually works in python.

Comment: I had suspected that. As you'll see, I mentioned I did it both ways.

Comment: @BraydonKains There must have been something else going on because as is, this works.

Comment: @BraydonKains: make sure the modules are in the same directory. Perhaps rename `test` to something else. Make sure you either import `aFunction` as a global, or refer to it via the module. `from test import aFunction` binds it as a global.

Comment: Renamed the file and 'from afilename import aFunction' worked. However, for the project I needed this info for, I need the files to be able to access eachothers' variables. Will 'from afilename import *' work?

Comment: @BraydonKains: You cannot move the shared variables to a separate module?

Comment: Sadly not, as these variables (lists) are defined in the primary module.

Comment: @BraydonKains: You'll either have to import those lists inside a function then (postpone importing until the function that needs them is called), or postpone triggering the circular import until *after* the lists are defined.

Comment: @BraydonKains: You really have a design problem, however. Circular imports mean the two modules are too interdependent.

Comment: I managed to get the function working in the main module, but still don't have a way to access the variables from the main module. Is it possible to pass lists as function arguments?

Comment: @BraydonKains: Yes, lists are just objects; you can pass them around as arguments just fine.

Comment: Okay, then I think I can make this work. Thank you for your help.